# Help with regular expression in grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

someone can explain me why this regexp doesn't work in grep?

```
ls -la ./ | grep -E '^d.*\<\..*\>$'
```

In my (wrong) opinion this have to show me the line of the directory with a name that start with ".", because:

- ^d -> keep lines that start with character "d"
- .* -> none or any combination of characters
- $ -> end of the line

The problem is that I don't understand this:

- \< -> start of the word
- . -> escape the point
- .* -> none or any combination of characters
- > -> end of the word

So I thought that this part of regexp keeps the lines that contain words that start with point and end with a combination of characters.

With this "ls -la" that regexp with grep shows none of result:

```
[arch dirtest]$ ls -la
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  6 siv users 4096 10 nov 00.41 .
drwx------ 59 siv users 4096  9 nov 23.15 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 siv users 4096 10 nov 00.41 .test
drwxr-xr-x  2 siv users 4096 10 nov 00.41 test1
drwxr-xr-x  2 siv users 4096 10 nov 00.41 test2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't work because `.` is not a word character. Grep only considers `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` to be word characters.

In any case, this is really not the right way to do this. First of all, parsing `ls` is [very fragile](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and almost never a good idea. Here are some other ways of listing directories whose name starts with a `.`:

```
find . -type d -name '.*'
```

Or, if you don't want it to descend into subdirectories (and if you have GNU `find`, the default on Linux):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d   -name '.*'
```

Alternatively, you could just use `echo` and a shell glob:

```
echo .*
```

That will also show files. To avoid that, use a loop like:

```
for i in .*; do [ -d "$i" ] && printf '%s\n' "$i"; done
```

Comment: Sorry, I mispell the parameter. The right parameter is "-E". Anyway I understand that it is not a good way to parse ls, but I have to do this in text for university so I can't modify this. Maybe this command may not work but the "right" answer for the test is that it finds directories with the name that start with a point. Don't you think so, too?

Comment: the "some reason" is that `.` isn't a word-constituent character as defined by grep.  word characters are letters, digits, and underscore.  so `\<\.` will never match anything.

Comment: @cas d'oh! Of course, I should have known. That's what I get for answering questions at 2am.

Comment: @siv-lab What is the question? No, parsing `ls` is never the right answer, whatever the question was. If your teacher told you you _have_ to use `ls`, then he's an idiot. And no, even if id did work, that would not find directories whose names start with a dot, only directories whose name contains a dot after a non-word character. So, for example `foo .bar` would also be found.

Comment: Yeah I get it, parsing "ls" is a bad way. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have omitted a device method after `-D`?

```
ls -la ./ | grep -D skip '^d.*\<\..*\>$'
```

Anyway ... the problem is that you're searching for a beginning-of-word
boundary, `\<`, followed by a literal dot, `\.`. This will always fail,
because a dot is not considered a word character. Quote from `info grep`
for GNU grep:

```
`-w'
`--word-regexp'
     ... Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

Replacing `\<` with a space seems to work reliably. However, I agree
with user:terdon that parsing the output from `ls -la` is fragile, and
there are better ways to get what you want.

Comment: Sorry I misspelled the parameter. The right parameter is "-E". So the problem is that the point is not considered a chatacter. I understand that parse "ls" is not a good idea but I have no other choices (see above the reply at terdon's comment). Thanks you